# Elasticsearch PHP Client - Bad

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using the PHP client.
I can search no problem.

My problem is getting suggestions.
Here is my code:

```
$json = '
POST /my_search_engine/_suggest
{
  "my_engine":{
    "text":"'.$keyword.'",
    "completion":{
      "field":"title_suggest"
    }
  }
}';

$params ['body'] = $json;
$response = $client->suggest ( $params );
```

Here is the stack trace:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception
>   'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception' with message
>   '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed
>   to derive
>   xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed
>   to derive xcontent"},"status":400}' in
>   /var/www/ats-site-lib/ats-site-thoracic/web/app/es_search/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:681
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /var/www/ats-site-lib/ats-site-thoracic/web/app/es_search/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(659):
>   Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->tryDeserializeError(Array,
>   'Elasticsearch\C...')
>   #1 /var/www/ats-site-lib/ats-site-thoracic/web/app/es_search/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(579):
>   Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->tryDeserialize400Error(Array)
>   #2 /var/www/ats-site-lib/ats-site-thoracic/web/app/es_search/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(261):
>   Elasticsearch in
>   **/var/www/ats-site-lib/ats-site-thoracic/web/app/es_search/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php**
>   on line **682**

Here is how a document's "title_suggest" completion field looks. I am storing an array of keywords. maybe this is the problem? :

> "title_suggest": [
>               "Membership",
>               "Renewal"
>             ]

Comment: You need to remove the line `POST /my_search_engine/_suggest` from your `$json` variable.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I was hoping is was something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make the JSON valid by removing `POST /my_search_engine/_suggest` from the string. Thanks to @Val

This is the end result:

```
$json = '
{
  "thoracic":{
    "text":"'.$keyword.'",
    "completion":{
      "field":"title_suggest"
    }
  }
}';
```